# What is void** in a S-Function .cpp

Tags: matlab, simulink, void, s-function

I am reading some code written in a .cpp file on which is based a MATLAB S-Function.

I just want to know what does it mean :

```
void** vecPWork
```

Is it a variable of which type? And the two stars stand for what?

thanks for your time.

Comment: My guess is it's a pointer on a pointer.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void **` is simply a *pointer to a pointer* to memory with an unspecified type.

Note: `void *` is a generic pointer type, but  `void **` is not a generic *pointer-to-pointer* type - as it *should* always point to a true `void * object`.

Also you can only dereference it once !